# Searching for filenames containing particular strings

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a program that will search a file for all names from a given state (NY, PA, etc.) and  District number (1,2,3, etc.). This needs to accept user input also.
What I have so far doesn't seem to work. 
I am unsure where to go from here. 
How do I finish this code?

This is what  I have so far:

```
def main():
    legislatorsTxtFile= open("legislators-all.txt","r")
    stateName= input("enter a state abv.")
    districtNum= input("enter district Number")
    R1= legislatorsTxtFile.readline()
    # while loop
    #

    R2= R1.split(",")
    if stateName in legislatorsTxtFile:
        print(stateName)
    print(legislatorsTxtFile)

main()
```

Here is a snipbit of the file:

```
last_name,first_name,birthday,gender,type,state,district,party

Zwach,John,2/8/07,M,rep,MN,6,Republican,

Zschau,Edwin,1/6/40,M,rep,CA,12,Republican

Zollicoffer,Felix,1812-05-19,M,rep,TN,8,American
```

Also I am using PyCharm.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry i didnt notice that i didnt put that in.

Comment: What's the content format of the file? How should "districtNum" variable be used?

Comment: The text file is a simple list the has last_name,first_name,birthday,gender,type,state,district,party for all the names and all separated by (,)

Comment: Could you post a sample of the file here? I think it'd be easier to debug if we can actually run the code here. Feel free to change the names, etc, but make sure the format stays the same.

Comment: Added a file sample, i would like the whole file but the file is stored in blackboard

Comment: What version of Python are you using? 2.7 can't evaluate input( ), in that case use raw_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
def main():
    legislatorsTxtFile = open("names.txt","r").read()
    stateName = raw_input("enter a state abv.")
    districtNum = raw_input("enter district Number")
    lines = legislatorsTxtFile.split('\n')
    matches = []
    for line in lines:
        cols = line.split(',')
        if stateName == cols[5] and districtNum == cols[6]:
            matches.append(line)

    print matches

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_line():
    legislatorsTxtFile="legislators-all.txt"
    stateName=input("enter a state abv.")
    districtNum=input("enter district Number")
    for i in open(legislatorsTxtFile, "r"):
        res = i.split(",")
        if res[5] == stateName and res[6] == districtNum:
            print i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    search_line()
```

if you don't need exact match both state and district in one line use:

```
if res[5] == stateName or res[6] == districtNum:
```